# How to load an ionic view according to the element who calls it?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am currently creating a restaurant app and i got stucked on this issue. I get a list of restaurant from the DB and i display them on a view using a ng-repeat. I display them in fom of card and on each card there are 2 links: one to get more infos about the restaurant and another one to get it's menu. Here comes the problem: i want to use the visit link to call a view and display the infos of the specific restaurant displayed on the card where the link was, with all it's informations. i want that view to be as a template so that it will just load a specific restaurant at a specific call, with all the informations. Please can someone help me?

Comment: You probably should add state to `ui.router` with url like `/restaurant/:id`, and in your DetailController that attached to that state you can have your `id` parameter.

Comment: can you give me an example please, so that i will understand better? thank you

Comment: I need some existing code from you.

Comment: ok @Leguest here is it:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that dislays the restaurants list:

```
    <ion-view view-title="RESTAURANTS A LA LISTE" class="plan">
   <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon icon button-clear ion-android-restaurant" ng-click="openModal()"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>
  <h3 class="assertive">{{error}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="record in records"
    <div class="list card" id="contenu">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img ng-src="{{record.logo}}">
    <h2>{{record.name}}</h2>
    <p class="assertive">{{record.devise}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-body">
    <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{record.photoune}}">
    <p>
      {{record.description}}
    </p>
    <p>
      <button class="button button-clear button-assertive subdued" ng-click="visite()">*Visiter</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-assertive subdued">*Menu</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here is the code to display the details of the restaurant:

```
    <ion-view view-title="{{record.name}}" class="plan">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon icon button-clear ion-android-restaurant" ng-click="openModal()"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>
  <div>
    <img src="{{record.photoune}}" class="headimg">
  </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Finally here is the restaurant list controller:

```
    .controller('listeCtrl', function($scope, Restaurants, $location){
  Restaurants.getRestaurants().then(function(restaurants){

        console.log("Restaurants: ", restaurants);
        console.log(restaurants.data);

        $scope.records =  restaurants.data.datas;
        $scope.visite = function(){
          $location.path('/visiteResto');
        };

      },function(error){
      console.log("Could not get location");
      $scope.error = "Desole, une erreur de connexion s'est produite!";
    }); 
})
```

I use a .factory and a php api to fetch the data from the db. here is the factory to get infos from the restaurant:

```
    .factory('Restaurants', function($http){
  var restaurants = [];
  return {
    getRestaurants: function(){
      return $http.get("http://192.168.8.101:80/feed.php").then(function(response){
          restaurants = response;
          return restaurants;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It's ok now @Leguest, i understood and applied your solution and it worked fine for me. Thanks a lot!!